# How to convert string to variable-name in scheme

Tags: string, variables, scheme

How can I achieve below in Scheme REPL? Create a variable name from a string.

> =>(define (string->variable-name "foo") 12)
>
> =>foo
>
> 12
>
> =>(+ foo 8)
>
> 20

[In Common Lisp, this should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306818/create-a-variable-name-from-a-string-in-lisp)

> => (set (intern "ANY-TEXT") 5)
>
> => ANY-TEXT
>
> 5

How do I build a #procedure like "string->variable-name" (and "variable-name->string") ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This really isn't something that you should want to do as it contradicts major design elements of Scheme.  (For example, while R6RS allowed one to introduce identifiers, R7RS retracted that capability).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Writing your own REPL is easy; but it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: A program language (like scheme) should have the ability to "creat variables though other variables". I am not a programmer but only a fan on programming, so if I was wrong please tell me.

Comment: Not every programming language does everything.  Scheme is a small language with a narrow focus; it is not designed to meet everybody's needs.  Conjuring identifiers bound to values, in a running program, is not a part of Scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you're passing to `string->variable-name` is *always* a string literal (i.e., *not* a variable that contains a string), you can do that using a `syntax-case` macro that transforms the string literal to an identifier:

```
(define-syntax string->variable-name
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ str)
       (string? (syntax->datum #'str))
       (datum->syntax #'str (string->symbol (syntax->datum #'str)))))))
```

and conversely, a `variable-name->string` macro could look like this:

```
(define-syntax variable-name->string
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ id)
       (identifier? #'id)
       (datum->syntax #'id (symbol->string (syntax->datum #'id)))))))
```

However, remember: this will only work if you are working with string (in case of `string->variable-name`) or identifier (in case of `variable-name->string`) literals.

---

If, on the other hand, you want the ability to reflect on names in your current Scheme environment, this is not supported by standard Scheme. Some implementations, like [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Module-System-Reflection.html) or [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html), do have this capability.

Here's a Guile example:

```
> (module-define! (current-module) 'foo 12)
> foo
12
> (define varname 'bar)
> (module-define! (current-module) varname 42)
> bar
42
```

and a Racket example:

```
> (namespace-set-variable-value! 'foo 12)
> foo
12
> (define varname 'bar)
> (namespace-set-variable-value! varname 42)
> bar
42
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Codes you mentioned don't work for me. Petite Chez Scheme complain "Exception: Exception: invalid syntax string->variable-name"
I'll try Racket later, I am using Windows, so it's hard for me to install Guile.

Comment: @ryrd How were you trying to call `string->syntax-name`? As I mentioned in my answer, it _only_ works when using string literals, e.g., `(string->syntax-name "foo")`. You _cannot_ use `(let ((foo "bar")) (string->syntax-name foo))`; I have a syntax guard in place to block that, and the error message suggests to me that you were indeed attempting such a thing and my guard caught it.

Comment: Yeap, I do want call `string->variable-name` as a regular #procedure, which also `(define foo "bar")(string->variable-name foo)` should work, and `bar` will also be a variable now.
I want to use it as a procedure, but thank you :-)

Comment: @ryrd What _are_ you trying to do at a high level, anyway? Poor-man's `eval`? I keep getting the feeling that we're dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13) here.

Comment: @ryrd Sorry, that's not "high level". High-level is basically explaining _why_ you're trying to do what you're doing. Like, are you _really_ trying to access top-level variables by name, or is it okay to use a hash table to hold a list of user-defined variables? If the latter is okay, there is a portable Scheme solution to your problem (and GoZoner's answer is a variant of that, except he/she is using [alists](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Association-Lists.html) instead of hash tables).

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting the syntax for a moment:

```
(define string->variable-name string->symbol)

(define name->value-mapping '())

(define (name-set! name value)
  (set! name->value-mapping
        (cons (cons name value)
              name->value-mapping))
  value)

(define (name-get name)
  (cond ((assoc name name->value-mapping) => cdr)
        (else 'unbound)))
```

Sure you can't do `(+ 5 <my-named-value>)` without some other help...