# Naming variables using variables in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, variable-assignment

If I have two variables, for example

```
(define x 10)
(define y 20)
```

And I want to create a new variable, using the values of ***x*** and ***y*** to create the name, how would I go about doing so?

For example let's say I want to make a new variable called ***variable-x-y***

```
(define variable-x-y "some-value")
```

In this case, ***x*** would be 10 and ***y*** would be 20.

Basically to summarize everything, I want to be able to enter ***variable-10-20*** and have it return ***"some-value"***

I'm sorry if this sounds like a novice question. I'm quite new to Racket.

**EDIT:**
Also, how would I  go about retrieving the values if just given the values of ***x*** and ***y*** (within the program)?

For example, let's say that somehow I was able to define the following:

```
(define variable-10-20 "some-value")

(define x 10)
(define y 20)
```

Is there a way for me to write ***variable-x-y*** and get back ***"some-value"***?

**EDIT 2**
Here is the simplified code of what I'm trying to implement. What it does is it recursively reads each individual element into a local variable which can then be used after it's all been "read in". I'm sure if you tweak the code using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176956/how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-scheme) it should work just fine.

```
(define (matrix->variables matrix)
  (local [(define (matrix2->variables/acc matrix2 x y)
            (cond
              [;; the entire matrix has "extracted" it's elements into variables
               (empty? matrix2)
               #|This is where the main program goes for using the variables|#]
              [;; the first row has "extracted" it's elements into variables
               (empty? (first matrix2))
               (matrix2->variables/acc (rest matrix2) 0 (add1 y))]
              [else (local [(define element-x-y "some-value")]
                      ;; Here is where I got stuck since I couldn't find a way to
                      ;; name the variable being created (element-x-y)
                      (matrix2->variables/acc
                       (cons (rest (first matrix2)) (rest matrix2))
                       (add1 x) y))]))]
    (matrix2->variables/acc matrix 0 0)))
```

Comment: Also, if just given the variables **x** and **y**, how would I go about retrieving the value of **variable-x-y** (within the program)? I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176956/how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-scheme

Comment: This would've been perfect if it weren't for the fact that I'm not allowed to use _define-syntax_ in my programs yet. Anyways, thanks for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how variable definition works. When you create a variable name, you have to *know* how to call it, you can't `define` names dynamically.

Perhaps a hash table for storing bindings will be useful, it's somewhat similar to what you ask and simulates having dynamically defined variables - but still I'm not sure *why* you want to do this, sounds more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Try this:

```
(define (create-key var1 var2)
  (string->symbol
   (string-append 
    "variable-"
    (number->string var1)
    "-"
    (number->string var2))))

; create a new "variable"
(define x 10)
(define y 20)
(create-key x y)
=> 'variable-10-20

; use a hash for storing "variables"
(define vars (make-hash))

; add a new "variable" to hash
(hash-set! vars (create-key x y) "some-value")

; retrieve the "variable" value from hash
(hash-ref vars 'variable-10-20)
=> "some-value"
```

Comment: So basically in my program, I'm working with a matrix and I don't want to keep processing the matrix to get it's values. I'm thinking of defining each element into a variable so that it can be called whenever I use it.

Comment: Implement the matrix as a vector of vectors and refer to each element using its indexes, that's how it's done in most programming languages. Creating dynamic variables for this is just plain wrong.

Comment: And yes, this _is_ an XY problem :P

Comment: Yeah, I've never heard of the XY problem up until now. Sorry about that, this is the first question that I've ever posted on Stackoverflow. Also thanks for referring me to it, I'll keep that in mind next time I post.

Do you know of a more efficient way to retrieve the values of a matrix? I'm currently limited to using lists for implementing matrices.

Comment: A vector will be more efficient, because it's designed for quickly accessing an element given its index. A list will also work, but finding an element with its index will be more costly, because all of the previous elements before it will have to be traversed first

Comment: Why not create a helper function `(create-getter matrix)`, that given your matrix returns a function that you can call with an x and y to return you your element?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing right now. The thing is though that every time I go to lookup an element in the matrix, I have to process the entire matrix (implemented as a list of list) which is 9x9. Since it's not too big of a matrix, I was thinking that it might be more efficient to create a helper function that "takes out" the values and creates variables for each element so that they can be accessed more efficiently. I'll edit the question with some of my actual code to hopefully make things more clear.

Comment: Actually, you *can* define variables whose names are generated at runtime, using `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what Mr. López said, variable names can be decided at runtime, but only at the top-level or module level. To do it in a module:

```
(compile-enforce-module-constants #f)
(eval `(define ,(string->symbol "foo") 'bar) (current-namespace))
```

Whether this is the right or wrong thing to do is a separate question entirely.

You'll run into the same problem when you try to access these variables, so you'll have to use `eval` there, too. You cannot export these variables with `provide`.

Comment: Hmmm... I haven't touched anything involving eval yet. What's the difference between using eval and the method used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176956/how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-scheme

Comment: `define-syntax` means you're writing a macro, and macros are expanded at compile time. `eval` happens at runtime. In Scheme and Common Lisp you can blur the distinction a little bit because compilation/macro-expansion and running can be interleaved, but in Racket you compile the modules first in a special compile-time environment that is strongly quarantined from the runtime environment, and then you run them after the bytecode files have been written to disk. So you can't have a macro that uses a string whose value isn't available until runtime.