# Is there an easy way to convert strings to variable names (identifiers) in Racket?

Tags: string, racket, identifier

I am pretty new in Racket and I have tried to do something that is really easy in other languages, such as PHP, which is converting a string to a variable name.
Something like:

```
#lang racket
(define t0 3)
(display t0) ; It outputs 3
(define (symbol? (string->symbol "t1")) 2 )
(display t1) ; It would output 2, however it throws an error :(
```

Is there a way to convert a string to identifier? Because I need to define variable names from strings, dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming variables using variables in Racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447853/naming-variables-using-variables-in-racket)

Comment: One of the benefits of Racket is that you always know at compile time when a variable is bound or unbound. This means that you can't create new variable bindings at run-time, *but*, you can define a macro to do this.

Comment: P.S. You sound like you're thinking of some of the same things I did before I knew any better, so I'll warn you, `eval` is *not* the answer. If you tell me what you want to use this for, I can tell you more about good solutions, including macros

Comment: I bet you will get a cleaner program if you use hash tables instead.

Comment: Indeed @soegaard hash tables are a very good solution for what I want to do. Many thanks to you and all the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed [soegaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23567/soegaard) hash tables are a very good solution, here is an example:

```
#lang racket
(define ht (make-hash))
(define sx "x")
(define sy "y")
(define sr "r")
(hash-set! ht sx 2)
(hash-set! ht sy 3)
(define r (+ (hash-ref ht sx) (hash-ref ht sy))) ;do calculation (+ 2 3)
(hash-set! ht sr r)
(hash-ref ht sr) ; it will output 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do what you want with the help of namespaces. However look into hash tables first.

```
#lang racket

(define-namespace-anchor here)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace here))

(define foo 42)
(parameterize ([current-namespace ns])
  (namespace-variable-value (string->symbol "foo")))
```

The output of this program is 42.

Comment: Namespaces lead to eval, eval leads to suffering?

Comment: @AlexKnauth Namespaces lead to eval, eval leads to the top-level, the top-level leads to hopelessness. ;)