# Racket language: How to convert string to variable-name

Tags: string, variables, dynamic, racket, definition

I am pretty new in Racket and I have tried to run [Chris Jester-Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young)'s solution ([How to convert string to variable-name in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176956/how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name-in-scheme)) to convert string to variable name (and its converse, in other words, conversing variable name to string):

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax string->variable-name
   (lambda (stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
     ((_ str)
       (string? (syntax->datum #'str))
         (datum->syntax #'str (string->symbol (syntax->datum #'str)))))))

(define-syntax variable-name->string
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ id)
       (identifier? #'id)
         (datum->syntax #'id (symbol->string (syntax->datum #'id)))))))
```

It was fine for `variable-name->string`, here an example:

```
>(define myvar 10)
>(variable-name->string myvar)
  "myvar"
```

However, I had no success with `string->variable-name`:

```
>(define (string->variable-name "myvar2") 4)
    error define: not an identifier, identifier with default, or keyword
    for procedure argument in: "myvar2"
```

I am using [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) 6.6, linux mint 17.3 64bits.

My main goal is how to convert a string to a variable name (identifier).

I was wondering:

1. to read a text file;
2. to get the name of the variables (string) from that text file; and
3. to use `define` to set the variable names with random integers.

Any help I will appreciate.

Comment: Use `(variable-name->string foo)` to invoke a macro with the name `variable-name->string`. The `(define (variable-name->string ...` means that you are defining a function named `variable-name->string` and since "myvar2" is not a legal name for a function argument, you get an error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? The macro that changes from a variable to a string does so compile time. The other way needs to be aswell so you can never make anything useful with these later.

Comment: Reading plain text file is a requirement for an academic work. Moreover, I have to build a program which is able to: 1- read a plain text file; 2- extract some strings from that plain text file; 3- assign that strings to variable names, dynamically; 4- do some calculation with that variables; and 5- finally, write down the outcomes to a plain text file.
I have got success in all those steps, in exception with step 3.

Comment: Hope you have learned what's happening.  @soegaard 's response is correct; just call `(define myvar2 1)` before the other call

Answer (score 0):

You may check answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764998/dynamically-create-ffi-methods-in-racket).

I was advised not to use strings but identifiers. So instead of having a plain text file you may use another Racket source with identifiers you want to use and just import this one.

Comment: Reading plain text file is a requirement for an academic work. Moreover, I have to build a program which is able to: 1- read a plain text file; 2- extract some strings from that plain text file; 3- assign that strings to variable names, dynamically; 4- do some calculation with that variables; and 5- finally, write down the outcomes to a plain text file.
I have got success in all those steps, in exception with step 3.

Comment: Trying to give more details of what I am trying to do:
`(define temp_var "Xi")` ;the string "Xi" was extracted from a text file.
`(define (display temp_var) 2 )`  ;is it the same of `(define Xi 2)`? 
`(display Xi)`   ;error Xi was not defined.
`(+ Xi 3)` ; is the outcome equals to 5?