# Symbols Produced By Intern

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

Here is a code snippet:

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-value (intern "foo")) 98)
98
CL-USER> foo
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE FOO {1003FC6213}>.
CL-USER> |foo|
98
```

The symbol created by `intern` has a `"|"` in front and end of the symbol I created. But in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318193/5345646), `foo` is set as the name of the symbol, not `|foo|`. So, why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(intern "foo")` is appearing as `|foo|` because intern is case sensitive.

See that in the answer you linked to that `(intern "FOO")` is capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the || is not a part of the symbol. It's just a character pair for escaping the enclosed symbol. This ensures that the exact case of the characters is used when reading the symbol.